# Is it possible to use php functions inside heredoc?

Tags: php, heredoc

Is it possible to use functions within the heredoc template without breaking it?
Somethig like this:

```
<<<HTML
   <div> showcaptcha(); </div>
HTML;
```

Specifically i wanna require another template in this one without using variables. 
Or is there another and more simple solution that is not using heredoc?
Thx in advanced.

**For example im using class named requires**.

```
class requires {

public function __construct(){
  $this->MYSQL();
  $this->FUNC();
}

public function MAIN_MENU() {
  require_once ('main-menu.tpl');
}

}
```

**Then what i do in index.php**

```
require_once ('requires.php');
$req = new requires();

echo <<<HTML
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>

//bla bla

</head>
<nav><ul class="fancynav">
{$req->HEAD_SCRIPTS()}
</ul></nav>
HTML;
```

**main-menu.tpl**

```
<li><a href="">Item</a></li>
<li><a href="">Item</a></li>
<li><a href="">Item</a></li>
<li><a href="">Item</a></li>
<li><a href="">Item</a></li>
```

**And in result i have an empty field without php error**

```
<nav><ul class="fancynav">



</ul></nav>
```

WTF?

Comment: Empty field because the ``HEAD_SCRIPTS()`` method does not return some string (and what's inserted in the ``HEREDOC`` is what the method returns). Instead of ``require_once()``, use ``return file_get_contents('*.tpl');``.

Comment: I found it. Required document prints on the bottom of the page, not in place where i set variable..

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can use the "encapsed var" trick:

```
function hello() {
    global $result;
    $result = 'hi there!';
    return 'result';
}

echo <<<EOF
text ${hello()} text
EOF;
```

Technically, this works, but it's better to avoid hacks like this in production. A temporary variable will be much cleaner.

Comment: *"it's better to allow hacks like this in production"* Missing a *not* here? Don't forget a ``global $result;`` if the ``echo`` is inside another function.

Comment: Thx I've got it. Then I'd better rewrite all the templates.

Answer (score 1):

Since you cannot directly call a function inside `HEREDOC`, you may put the function name in a variable, and use that variable inside the `HEREDOC` string:

```
    $showcaptcha= 'showcaptcha';
    echo
<<<HTML
    <br/> dawg {$showcaptcha()} dawg
HTML;
```

So you can leave the current already coded function:

```
    function showcaptcha()
    {
        return "Gotta captcha mall";
    }
```

You could also use:

```
    $showcaptcha = function()
    {
        return "Gotta captcha mall";
    }
    echo
<<<HTML
    <br/> dawg {$showcaptcha()} dawg
HTML;
```

If the function to call is defined at the same level as the echo (else, you'll have a global variable `$showcaptcha`).

If you have several functions, you can make a loop before the heredoc:

```
    function dawg()
    {
        return "I'm loyal";
    }
    function cat()
    {
        return "I'm cute";
    }
    function fish()
    {
        return "I'm small";
    }
    function elephant()
    {
        return "I'm big";
    }

    $functionsToCall = array('elephant', 'fish', 'cat', 'dawg');
    foreach ($functionsToCall as $functionToCall)
        $$functionToCall = $functionToCall;
    echo
<<<HTML
    <br/> Dawg: {$dawg()}
    <br/> Cat: {$cat()}
    <br/> Fish: {$fish()}
    <br/> Elephant: {$elephant()}
HTML;
```

That's way less ugly than using a global variable

Comment: If you're using a temp variable anyways, you don't need the encaps trick at all. Just interpolate it normally.

Comment: @georg Sorry, I don't get it... What do you mean?

Comment: `$temp = func(); echo <<<HTML $temp HTML;`

Comment: Oh, yes, but I assumed that the function is set somewhere else (since it's not shown), so temp variable avoid having to edit that code somewhere else.

Comment: hm. i decided to use class with list of functions that requires documents. but have an obscure bug. added code to the question.

Answer (score -2):

No, it is not possible to use function inside heredoc strings.