# PHP print_r function within heredoc string?

Tags: php, heredoc

I've tried a few different ways and per [Is it possible to use php functions inside heredoc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26078506/is-it-possible-to-use-php-functions-inside-heredoc) it seems like the first one (for the GET) should work?

But it doesn't.  Any way to do this simply, or should I just manually include the debug section?

```
  function bottom_module() {
    $print_r = print_r;

    $html = <<<"OUTPUT"
      <footer>
        ...
      </footer>

      <aside id="debug">
        <hr>
        <h3>Debug Area</h3>
        <pre>
          GET Contains:
          {$print_r($_GET)}
          POST Contains:
          $print_r($_POST)
          SESSION Contains:
          print_r($_SESSION)
        </pre>
      </aside>

    </body>
  </html>
  OUTPUT;
    echo $html;
  }
```

Comment: Unrelated to the problem you're currently having, but `$print_r = print_r;` refers to a _constant_ called `print_r`. What you almost certainly intended to write was `$print_r = 'print_r';` - that is, set `$print_r` to be a _string_ with the content `'print_r'`. In old versions of PHP, an odd feature guessed that undefined constants were intended to be strings, but it _always_ issued a Notice or Warning while doing so, and the feature was removed in PHP 8.0 so it is an error instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you will probably find is that the `print_r()` is displaying the value rather than including it in the output.

You should try using the second parameter which if set to true will return the value as a string instead...

```
   <pre>
      GET Contains:
      {$print_r($_GET, true)}
```

EDIT from OP for clarity: this solves the issue but as another reply said, $print_r must be declared as `$print_r = 'print_r';`